# Retina macbook max USB power output

Tags: usb, macbook-pro, power, charging

Could someone tell me how much Amperes (Amps) the Retina MacBook Pro can deliver over USB?

I thought that one should be able to charge an iPad with a Retina MacBook which would mean that it should be about 1A minimum (probably rather 2-5A for an iPad3). However when I plug in my Android phone to charge, it does charge slower than on an 1A USB charger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macs with USB 2.0 from the last few years can generally provide 1.0A via USB. The USB 3.0 standard specifies 900mA; I suspect that USB3 Macs still provide 1A or even a little more. Note however, that in order for a device to actually draw that much, it must specifically request it from the bus. Apple's iDevices certainly do this, as you can see in **System Profiler** (as mentioned in the other answer). For a USB 2.0 device to request more than 500mA, it must implement a special protocol extension, which few devices follow. The reason those devices might still draw 1A from a pure charger is because they detect that the data lines are not connected in the usual way.

Likewise, the iPad only draws 1.0A when connected to a Mac (or even 500mA from most PCs), but 2.0A when connected to the special iPad charger. The charger has its data pins pulled to special indicator voltages via a potential divider, and the iPad only draws that much current if it detects this configuration to avoid damaging whatever it's plugged into.

Comment: `Mac with USB2.0 ... generally provide 1.0A` [This KB article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4049) states it's 500mA for USB2.0. Do you have a source for the 1.0A number?

Comment: That's not true, when an iPad connect to macbook, it will give a 2.1A output. See this: https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204377

Answer (score 3):

With the **System Profiler** you'll be able to know how much power does the USB delivers, and how much is required for each device connected to a USB. Under the *Hardware* tab, you'll find, listed, all the USB ports, and, within, all the devices connected to them. Just select one of those to get detailed information.

To open *System Profiler* just choose **Apple Menu / About this Mac** and clicking *More Info*, or go to **Applications / Utilities**.

Comment: "System Profiler" -- easiest way to find this is to use spotlight search; in Sierra the USB data is under "System Report..." button in System Profiler

Answer (score 2):

With a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013)

I got this when charging an iPad, which is 2100mA in total.

[image]

Comment: Where did you get this information?

Answer (score 0):

I have a Late 2013 MacBook Pro. The output with a iPhone 7 Plus connected to the USB 3 Left port is 1.8 Amps. Verified using a USB power meter dongle. This only happens once the iPhone has booted. Before booting, the iPhone takes only .38 amps.

System profiler shows the following:

```
Current Available (mA): 500
Current Required (mA):  500
**Extra Operating Current (mA): 1600**
Sleep current (mA): 2100
```

So it seems the MacBook Pros can indeed output approximately 2 amps. Which should be enough to fast-charge at least the iPhone X.

[image: Mac System Profiler outputs 1.8 Amps on USB]

Answer (score 0):

The maximum amount of power that your MacBook or Apple Display can provide depends on whether it has USB 2 or USB 3 ports.

- USB 2 - 500mA
- USB 3 - 900mA

See [Using USB devices with your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201163) for complete details.

System Information (Apple menu  > About This Mac) can give you more details about USB power.

- Current Available is the default amount of power available to your device
- Current Required is what the device is asking for
- Extra Operating Current is extra current available to ***certain Apple devices like iPhones and iPads***.

Source:  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204377

[image]

#### TL;DR

The maximum amount of power is dependent on whether you have USB 2 or USB 3 ports, 500maA and 900mA respectively.  However, if you plug in certain Apple devices, there is *extra* current available which your device can use.  It's not generally available to all devices (like Android phones or tablets)